# ng-Grid Pagination - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

```
   <div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">    
     <table ng-grid >
        <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <td >{{todo.name}}</td>
            <td >{{todo.estimate | number}}</td>
            <td width="50">{{todo.done }}</td>
            <td title="Create At">{{todo.created_at | date}}</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
```

And the javascript code is in http://jsfiddle.net/dalcib/J3fjc/ . I am new to AngularJS, I can understand the above html. Would someone please explain me what's really done there in the javascript?

It's one of the answers for [How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From and Angular perspective, this is probably the most interesting javascript line:

```
angular.module('ngGrid', ['ngSkip']).directive('ngGrid', function() {
```

The line is doing two things.  First defining an Angular [module](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), and second, defining a new [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) inside that module (named `ngGrid`).  (As a side note, there is another very [big project named ngGrid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/), and this does not seem to be related).

You'll see that inside the directive, an object is being built up and returned (`direc`).  This defines the configuration of the directive.  Once you read the [Angular Directive documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), the structure of the code should start to make sense.

I must say, you've picked a pretty sketchy example to start to understand.  Perhaps, it would be better to start with the [Angular Tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) and build up from there.

A quick definition from the docs of what a directive is:

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an
>   attribute, element name, or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML
>   compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element
>   or even transform the DOM element and its children.
>
> Angular comes with a set of these directives built-in, like ngBind,
>   ngModel, and ngView. Much like you create controllers and services,
>   you can create your own directives for Angular to use. When Angular
>   bootstraps your application, the HTML compiler traverses the DOM
>   matching directives against the DOM elements.

Comment: So it's a custom directive and has got nothing to do with http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ !! I thought I could add that pagination controls to an ng-grid in my project, since the pagination that comes with ng-grid seems to have issues displaying the currentPage. Ty, that helped!