# How to paginate result using AngularJS yet filtering on the complete list?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-filter

Examples and links from [How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs) all show pagination system where the filtering/ordering only apply to current page.

For instance, [sorting by `id` on the 1st page of this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/11/) will switch :

- between: `1, 10, 11, 12, 13` ;
- and this : `13, 12, 11, 10, 1`.

While someone might expects to get :

- `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` (as those values are present in following pages).

#### Question

How would someone **filter/order *then* paginate** instead of paginate then filter a list ?

Comment: are you concerned about the sorting algorithm as well, or just sorting on the entire set? If we apply the same sorting algorithm to the entire set, the values one should expect are `1, 10, 11, 12, 13`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1) Stop sorting on paged results

Before:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
```

After:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage]">
```

### 2) Inject `$filter` and sort on the entire set

```
$filter('orderBy')($scope.items, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
```

### ... [Here is a modified fork](http://jsfiddle.net/JeUZ6/1/) of your fiddle

Comment: Thanks, that's what I finally did. however the sorting is kind of slow, I will need to update my question to give more details.

Comment: I updated the link in my answer and it's a little faster now.