# data retrieve in Ionic from WordPress JSON API

Tags: json, wordpress, angularjs, ionic-framework

I retrieve data from WordPress through JSON API to Ionic but in WordPress JSON API only 10 data is retrieved.

How to retrieve the next 10 posts with on-screen loader in Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use bootstrap pagination, code here : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

more spec here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/docs/readme.md

working plunker here:
[How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs)