# Add paging to instagram API using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, instagram, instagram-api

I want to show instgram image based on user account and tags and merge two `API` results to show them as one.

I am not sure how to add paging functionality to this. a simple scroll based loading will work also.

```
div(ng-app="app")
  div(ng-controller='InstagramCtrl')
    p Total number of photos: {{photos.length}} 
      ul
        li(ng-repeat='photo in photos | orderBy:"-created_time"' )
          a(href='{{photo.link}}')
            img(src='{{ photo.images.low_resolution.url }}')
```

code-pen sample http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPBwNE

I question is in context with instagram API. example seems to be advance for me as i am not a scripting guy i am from design background. Any help is appreciate to solve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do paging in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs)

Comment: Also, looking at the documentation, the Instagram api call provides for pagination urls: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: Sorry guys example seems to be advance for me as i am not from programing side and am more on design side..