# angularjs + ui.bootstrap pagination wrong total pages number

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

Can't comment the main post, so need to post new question.

I'm trying to implement the pagination solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs) thread, written by [Scotty.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123275/scotty-net)(the top rated answer), but facing a strange issue:

My custom code is in this plunker(http://plnkr.co/edit/Mdsy2x) and explains the issue. If I set `$scope.numPerPage` as any number except '10' - I'm getting wrong total pages number. For example if I generate 450 todo's and set in `$scope.numPerPage = 5;` - I get a total of 45 pages and 225 items showed and so any number except 10 give wrong result

Comment: Using your plunker, the maximum pages is 100. Maybe the `pagination` module is the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you you just need to add the `items-per-page` attribute:

```
<pagination 
      total-items="todos.length" 
      items-per-page="numPerPage"
      ng-model="currentPage" 
      max-size="maxSize"
      class="pagination-sm" 
      boundary-links="true">
  </pagination>
```

It's default value is 10, that's why it worked well only with 10 items per page.