# AngularJs pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to make pagination so I follow this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs?)(mostvoted answer) and also [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview) but my pagination not working perfect so I tested the original plunker and problem is also there [to see the problem set values

```
$scope.totalItems = 16;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.itemsPerPage = 4;
```

]
here I should get 4 pages 16/4=4;

Do anyone have a good angularJs pagination looks like this one(UI)?

Comment: you have to set `items-per-page="numPerPage"` , in the plunker you provided, for it to work else it defaults to 10

Comment: setting item per page in html should work