# AngularJS limitTo filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, single-page-application, performance-testing

I understand that in AngularJS the filter called "limitTo" is used to limit the data.

Lets say that we have a 100 records and we limit the data to 10 records using
the limitTo filter.

Now how can i display the remaining 90 records.
I need some sort of next and previous button on the bottom which 
should show me the next 10 records when i click on it and so on.

How can i achieve this without compromising any performance.
Please provide code if you can. Thanks... :-)

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

Per the [limitTo docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) there are arguments for `start` and `limit`

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

So you can use scope variables for those arguments as per this simple example:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items|limitTo:limit:start">{{item.name}}</p>
<button ng-click="next()" ng-if="start < items.length-10">Next</button>
<button ng-click="prev()" ng-if="start >0">Prev</button>
```

JS

```
  $scope.start = 0;
  $scope.limit = 10;
  $scope.items = [/* some data*/];      

  $scope.next = function() {
    incrementLimit(true)
  }
  $scope.prev = function() {
    incrementLimit(false)
  }

  function incrementLimit(up) {
    if (up) {
      ($scope.start <= ($scope.items.length - $scope.limit)) ? $scope.start += 10: $scope.start = 0;
    } else {
      $scope.start > 10 ? $scope.start -= 10 : $scope.start = 0;

    }
  }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6waGasW0H3L1UX5fXv6t?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The `limitTo` filter has an optional start parameter.

Set a variable e.g. `$scope.start = 0`

You can then setup your filter as `limitTo : 10 : start` and when you click the button just increment `$scope.start` by 10.

[angularjs limitTo documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo), it is  automatic if u use this-

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

U can try this example-

```js
var todos = angular.module('todos', ['ui.bootstrap']);

todos.controller('TodoController', function($scope) {
   $scope.filteredTodos = []
  ,$scope.currentPage = 1
  ,$scope.numPerPage = 10
  ,$scope.maxSize = 5;
  
  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.todos = [];
    for (i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
      $scope.todos.push({ text:'todo '+i, done:false});
    }
  };
  $scope.makeTodos(); 
  
  $scope.numPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.todos.length / $scope.numPerPage);
  };
  
  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    
    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
  });
});
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@2.3.2" data-semver="2.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />

<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.3.0" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.min.js"></script>


<h1>Todos</h1>
<h4>{{todos.length}} remain</h4>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="todo in filteredTodos">{{todo.text}}</li>
</ul>
<div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numPages()" 
  data-current-page="currentPage" data-max-size="maxSize"  
  data-boundary-links="true">
</div>
```

Runnable code can be found here-

http://plnkr.co/edit/ItgGWIq5ZhzgBYmWJ68y?p=preview