# Windows event log consuming too much time while fetch and display the data

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, typescript1.8

I am trying to fetch and display the windows event log in to the table. It takes almost 7 sec to fetch and display it on client side windows log entries are of more than 150000 and it increase with time. I need to show the data in table using pagination. I need help regarding pagination using angular 2 to show the data and other help regarding time to display the logs because logs generate real time without knowing how it occurs. and where i implement the pagination concept client side or server side.

### Api Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Eventlogg> Get()
{
 EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application", "nb-ahja1", "EventLoggingApp");

            var model = new List<Eventlogg>();
            foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
            { 
                var demo = new Eventlogg();
                demo.Source = log.Source;
                demo.Id = log.EventID;
                demo.Level = log.EntryType.ToString();
                demo.Date = log.TimeGenerated;
                demo.Category = log.Category;
                model.Add(demo);
            }
            return model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
        }
```

### Angular 2 web api calling

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {EventLogModel} from '../models/eventlogmodel';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Component({
    template: `
<table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-3"><b>Level</b></td>
                <td class="col-md-3"><b>Date</b></td>
                <td class="col-md-3"><b>Source</b></td>
                <td class="col-md-3"><b>Id</b></td>
                <td class="col-md-3"><b>Category</b></td>
            </tr>

            <tr *ngFor="let model of models">
                <td class="col-md-3">{{model.level}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-3">{{model.date}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-3">{{model.source}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-3">{{model.id}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-3">{{model.category}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
`
})

export class BootstrapJavascriptComponent {

    models: Array<EventLogModel> = [];

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.getData();
    }
    //api calling from server
    getData() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:54363/api/data')
            .map(res => (<Response>res).json())
            .map((models: Array<any>) => {
                let result: Array<EventLogModel> = [];
                if (models) {
                    models.forEach(model => {
                        result.push(
                            new EventLogModel(
                                model.id,
                                model.source,
                                model.level,
                                model.category,
                                new Date(model.date)
                                ));
                    });
                }

                return result;
            }).
            subscribe(
            data => {
                this.models = data;
                console.log(this.models);
            },
            err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
}
```

### Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PocDashboard.Models
{
    public class Eventlogg
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where i implement the pagination concept client side or server side

**Server side pagination is better for:**

1. Large data set
2. Faster initial page load
3. Accessibility for those not running JavaScript
4. Complex view business logic
5. Resilience to concurrent changes

**Client side pagination is better for:**

1. Small data set
2. Faster subsequent page loads
3. Sort & filter requirements supported fully (unless results greater than max size).

[How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs)

Comment: I got one answers from you. now i get this to implement pagination on server side. now my other question is how i can paginate it?? is system.diagnostic give this fine of functionality???

Comment: defiantly, system.diagnostic give you best functionality