# Read huge data from java to angular js

Tags: java, angularjs, cassandra, streaming

I am trying to read 100000 records from java mainly from cassandra to angular js and download in a file in GUI. But the page get hanged up moment it get huge data.

What can be an optimal solution.

Thanks

Comment: use paging mechanism

Comment: How... it will be great if u provide some reference.. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs

Comment: This will give pagination .. but i want to download huge data as a file in browser..

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data in packet rather then downloading the whole data in one way.

Comment: ya you can but get the data in packet or bucket rather than using whole data in one shot.