# Slicing JSON into an array ahead of pagination in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, pagination, slice

I am following the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs) about paging in Angular JS. When I put the example on my site it works. But when I try to change the data in the scope to my JSON formatted data it no longer works.

`myData.length` gives the correct count, but `filteredmyData` ends up just being an empty array

I'm not sure what I need to investigate next. Any help appreciated.

**App and controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("resource-database.json").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });

  $scope.filteredmyData = []
  ,$scope.currentPage = 1
  ,$scope.numPerPage = 3
  ,$scope.maxSize = 5;


  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.filteredmyData = $scope.myData.slice(begin, end);
  }); 
});
```

**resource-database.json**

```
{"records": [
    {
        "id":"8",
        "resource_name":"title of resource",
       "resource_source":"web address"
    },
....
]}
```

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary. Please, provide a plunk or a fiddle if you can't debug the app by yourself. But the code above will result in error because `myData` is initially undefined. I guess you haven't checked the console for errors, so this is the first thing you can do.

Comment: $scope.myData = response.data.records;