# How can I use pagination with url in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

How can I use pagination with url in angularjs?

For example
`<a ng-href="#/list?page='{{i}}'">`

Comment: No need of `'` just use `<a ng-href="#/list?page={{i}}">{{i}}</a>`

Comment: Thank you but I do not know how cotorller should come up with paging url information.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. go through [pagination in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a url method.