# Only render items when visible

Tags: angularjs, performance

I've got a big table, about 500 columns, which is about 25000 pixels wide total.
And it's not very good to render it all at once.

But I have zero to none ideas how to only render the part of the table that is visible on the screen, which is a section that is about 1200px wide. (On my screen, depends on other people's screens).

Here's some code

```
<tr ng-repeat="shift in ctrl.items">
    <td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.calculateNumberOfColumns() track by $index"></td>
</tr>
```

Only idea I have is somehow attaching `ng-if` to each `td`, but that seems like a rather bad idea.

So I'm hoping someone else has any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to improve performances when ng-repeating over a lot of data, there are two common solutions:

## Paginate the result

You can use for exemple the AngularUI [`pagination`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/pagination) directive. See also [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs) dealing with how to use it on an Angular app.

## Use the `limitTo` filter

This solution will be less good in terms of performance, but may be better adapted to your needs (you won't have to edit server side).

[`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) is a core Angular directive that allow you limit the amount of lines displayed by a `ng-repeat` (in the following example, 50):

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 50">{{item}}</tr>
```

Note that you can move the `limit` value to a scope variable. You can modify it to update the number of items you want to display:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.limit = 5; // default limit
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) $scope.items.push(i); // generate data
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items | limitTo: limit">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="limit = limit + 5">Show more results</button>
</div>
```