# Params with url AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have question in relation with $location service in AngularJS. I set url when I click at a button :

```
$location.path('pageNumber='+$scope.page+'&'+'pageSize='+$scope.pageSize);
```

Now question is how can I write variables from URL, and how can I check If exists variable for example: pageSize

Comment: if you are tying to make pagination using angular check this
[How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs)

Comment: did you set your $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$location.search()` on the controller of the redirected page.

`$location.search()` returns an object, consisting of the keys as variables and the values as its value. So, if you write your query string like this:

```
?pageNumber=5&pageSize=10
```

Then you can get the value for `pageNumber` and `pageSize` like this,

```
$scope.pageNumber = $location.search().pageNumber;
$scope.pageSize = $location.search().pageSize
```

And you can now check for existence like this

```
if(angular.isDefined($scope.pageNumber)){
  //true if pageNumber exist
}

if(angular.isDefined($scope.pageSize )){
 ////true if pageSize exist
}
```

One think to consider here is that this will not work with hashbang in Angular. You will get empty value(object) for `$location.search()`. At this time you need to explicitly define this in your config:

```
moduleName.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    
}]);
```

OR

If you do not want to use `html5Mode` since you need a server route for page refresh then you can use the javascript way to get the query string like below:

```
function getQueryString(name) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and inside your controller you need to initialize like this

```
$scope.pageNumber = getQueryString('pageNumber');
$scope.pageSize = getQueryString('pageSize');
```

And you can now check for existence like this

```
if(angular.isDefined($scope.pageNumber)){
  //true if pageNumber exist
}

if(angular.isDefined($scope.pageSize )){
 ////true if pageSize exist
}
```

Comment: did you set your $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: I correct on: 
product.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){  
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
}]); 
Now i have problem, why when i click in nav on link url will change but site dont change, only after refresh??

Comment: You need to define a route for all pages in your server so that when the page is refreshed that server route is accessed and return you the path of master page of Angular where you have ng-view (or ui-view)

Comment: You mean, that I have to create ngRoute?? Because I have don't so far on nodeJS routing

Comment: Ok lets go for a javascript solution. Check my updated answer. You can use that. It is a proper solution for query string.

Comment: let me know if you still need further help.

Comment: Tell me, if i useing html5Mode  why when i change site i must after it refresh site??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148229/discussion-between-aka-and-turqus).

Comment: Because you need to provide a base path that overrides the existing angular #/ path and the routes which we specify is relative to #/ . Now when you refresh the page the browser directly look for the page without # and there is no such page found as there is no such routes for that page without hash.