# How do I show only 5 results by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have a search bar, by default it's loading all the data under the search bar.
I want to limit the default before searching to be only 5 results in the table.

I'm trying this but it doesn't work!
What I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
            $('#result').dataTable({'iDisplayLength': 5});
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the HTML part is just this code:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: do you mean something like pagination?

Comment: Is this something like _autocomplete_?

Comment: Yes, I want to limit the data to be only 5 result to make it pagination

Comment: Try `pageLength` instead.

Comment: Are you using an external library to implement that autocomplete?

Comment: @yunzen no, it's connected to mysql database, this script for searching inside that database

Comment: Try moving the `$('#result').dataTable({'iDisplayLength': 5});` into your ajax `success` method instead of the `$('#result').html(data);`

Comment: @RafaRomero I have other file with database info and at the end is this "echo $output;" should I control it from there instead?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I did, it's still the same

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I move it, but it show nothing at all, no result befure or after the search

Comment: I'm trying to make it look like this example @rai https://www.phpflow.com/demo/jquery_pagination_with_php_demo/index.php?page=6

Comment: one question @jason5137715. Do you want to retrieve data `5` each or retrieve all and display `5` in each page?

Comment: I want to retrieve all and limit it to 5 results by page

Comment: that'd be easy.. can you add your html part to the question?

Comment: are you using angular or the like?

Comment: @Rai the html part is so simple just "<div id="result"></div>"

Comment: I'm trying to make exaclty like this example https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/sorting-filtering-pagination-fancytable/

Comment: If you're using angular... [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs) should come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using datatbles then you have to pass `pageLength: 5`.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 5
} );
```

you can see in this [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength)